# Adding permissions to ACL

Tags: php, symfony, acl

Because there is so little documentation, it's been hard learning the ins and outs of Symfony2's ACL system, but so far I've managed to understand most of the concepts. However, there is one problem...

I would like to be able to add a permission `ADMIN` that inherits the same conditions as `OWNER` for use with ACL. My goal would be to designate admin controls within the post page, but also give admins access to other controls granted to owners.

If anyone can provide clear examples, documentation, or links as assistance would be greatly appreciated and even a nudge in the right path is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html#cumulative-permissions)

```
$builder = new MaskBuilder();
$builder
    ->add('owner')
;
$mask = $builder->get();

$acl->insertObjectAce(new UserSecurityIdentity('user1'), $mask);
```

And then apply the same mask to your "ADMIN" user.

Is that what you're looking for? Hope that helped a bit anyway ;)

Comment: I need the masks to be different as the "ADMIN" mask allows for additional options (such as moving the post) on top of the ones it should inherit from OWNER. My question is geared towards extending the ACL system to add more permissions and how to have those permissions inherit other permissions.